# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get some company logos to display in 4 column table. this is the code i have. if i just display them without the result going in to 2 or more columns i get this error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

my code :-

```
 <td><table width="100%" border="0">
        <?php 

            $sqlShowLOGO = "SELECT filename FROM tblcompanylogo" ;
            $resultShowLOGO = mysqli_query($con, $sqlShowLOGO);
            $record_count = 0;
                while ($rowLOGO = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultShowLOGO))
                {

    if ($record_count % 4==0 && $record_count != 0)
    {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo '<td>';

    for ($i=0; $i< count($rowLOGO); $i++)
    {
        echo $rowLOGO[$i];
    }
    echo '</td>';

    $record_count++;
        }
        ?>
      </table></td>
```

Can someone please  help me to correct this issue

Comment: Associative arrays do not carry numeric-based keys.

Comment: Try using mysqli_fetch_array instead: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: You're also missing your opening `<tr>` before the loop and ending `</tr>` after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` function fetches a result row as an associative array(not indexed).
The line `echo $rowLOGO[0];` in your case will throw `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 ...`
Replace this loop

```
for ($i=0; $i< count($rowLOGO); $i++)
{
    echo $rowLOGO[$i];
}
```

with the following line `echo $rowLOGO['filename'];`

Comment: It Works. changing it to echo $rowLOGO['filename']; and using mysqli_fetch_array. Thank you all a lot

Comment: I have got another problem. now its only displaying the logos in one row. i want it to spread along 4 columns.

Comment: @Ruchith, you need to add opening tag `<tr>` right after the opening `<table>` tag and closing `</tag>` before the closing `</table>` tag

Answer (score 0):

As you might have already about knew the error. This is due to trying to access the empty array or trying to access the value of empty key of array. In my project, I am dealing with this error with counting the array and displaying result.